# ExpressJet IATA code before "merger" with Atlantic Southeast?

Tags: usa, airlines, iata

Before 2011, Atlantic Southeast had the IATA 2-letter code "EV". Then,

> On November 22, 2011, both ExpressJet and Atlantic Southeast Airlines achieved a single operating certificate that allowed them to operate as one carrier, using Atlantic Southeast's former call sign "Acey". Effective December 31, 2011, all flights began operating under the name ExpressJet.[7] ExpressJet currently operates as United Airlines Express.

(so [says Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressJet).)

What IATA code(s) did ExpressJet, or airlines which became ExpressJet, use until that time?

Answer (score 3):

By looking at the Wikipedia article history, one finds that on [8 November 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ExpressJet&oldid=459557788) (before the merger), the IATA code for ExpressJet was **XE**, the ICAO code was **BTA** and callsign was **JET LINK**.

Comment: Oh... clever trick. Should have thought of that myself. Thank you. But - was this the only code?

Comment: [This revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ExpressJet&direction=next&oldid=36995496) claimes **RU**, and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ExpressJet&direction=next&oldid=93917986) changed it to **XE**.